# how to convert drools project to maven java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, drools

I have converted my existed maven project to Drools project through eclipse. I right clicked on project and went to Configure tab and selected an option "Convert to Drools project". Now while compiling this code it throws an error as below

> [ERROR] /C:/Users/praveen.joshi/git/Sample/Services/src/main/java/com/sample/dashboard/ruleEngine/DroolsTest.java:[15,17] cannot find symbol
>     symbol:   class KieServices
>     location: class com.sample.dashboard.ruleEngine.DroolsTest

I am using Java 8

Comment: Provide the kie jars in the classpath

Comment: I have provided them in pom.xml